# Is it possible to get login time from facebook server?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

We are trying to provide facebook login to our android application. Is it possible to get login time from facebook server at the time of login? I'm new to facebook apps. Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get access to the authentication token via the `AccessToken` object. This has a method `getLastRefresh()` which returns a date of the last time the token was updated. More information here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/AccessToken

Of course, given that many people are constantly logged into facebook these days, this date may well be quite old, I'm unfamiliar with how often it gets updated. That'll be something to look into.

Comment: Thank you so much... I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: I tried getAccessToken(), but that is returning a String object. Can u suggest me how i can get an AccessToken object?

Comment: I would use something like: <code>AccessToken token = new AccessToken();</code> <code>token.getLastRefresh();</code> Into a date object. None of this code is tested. You will have to call <code>getLastRefresh()</code> on the AccessToken object to get the date. HTH.

Comment: Thank u LokiSinclair...  But I am not able to create AccessToken object like that. Can you suggest some other ways..
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you require more help, you're going to have to post code, so I can see what you're using to access facebook objects. Otherwise, there are just too many factors to consider. If you edit your original question with some code examples of how you're wanting to integrate facebook sdk, I may well be able to point you in the right direction.